# The use of the word "Holy One"

Tags: word-study

The old testament talks about the Holy One of Israel(Isaiah 30:11),could it be referring to Jesus or King David?

Answer (score 1):

*Holy One and King in the Old Testament*

The Holy One of Israel refers to God in the old testament(not king David).

> Thus says the LORD your Redeemer,**the Holy One of Israel**: “For your sake, I will send to Babylon and bring them all as fugitives, even the Chaldeans, in the ships in which they rejoice. I am the LORD, your **Holy One**, the Creator of Israel, and your **King**.”Isaiah 43:15

Notice also the use of the word "King" in Isaiah 43:15. It refers to the only legitimate King of Israel, prophesied in Zechariah 9:9.

> Rejoice greatly, O daughter of Zion! Shout, O daughter of Jerusalem! Behold, your **King** is coming to you; He is just and having salvation, Lowly and riding on a donkey, A colt, the foal of a donkey. Zechariah 9:9

*Holy One and King in the New Testament*

Magi came to worship Jesus saying that He was a King.

> “Where is the One who has been born King of the Jews? We saw His star in the east and have come to worship Him.”Matthew 2:2

When Jesus is questioned about being the King of the Jews, He implies that indeed He is.

> So Pilate asked Him, “Are You the King of the Jews?” “You have said so,” Jesus replied. Luke 23:3

Demons called out Jesus for being the Holy One(refer back to Isaiah 43:15).

> "What do You want with us, Jesus of Nazareth? Have You come to destroy us? I know who You are--the Holy One of God!" Mark 1:24

**Conclusion:** The term King and Holy One refer to Jesus who came from heaven and ascended to heaven,it surely does not refer to an earthly king or an earthly holy person.

Comment: It is not a criticism of any kind (I voted up both your question and your answer) but it is better to leave a question for a few days, to allow others to respond, before answering it yourself. Unlike social media sites, most people will only visit this site every few days or even weekly - not hourly.